# Unable to restart Apache with httpd running on port:80

Tags: apache

```
systemctl restart apache2
```

gives error .When looking at

```
sudo journalctl -xe
```

gives

> Jun 22 18:18:02 satyam-GL63-8RD apachectl[24434]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not
>   Jun 22 18:18:02 satyam-GL63-8RD apachectl[24434]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not
>   Jun 22 18:18:02 satyam-GL63-8RD apachectl[24434]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
>   Jun 22 18:18:02 satyam-GL63-8RD apachectl[24434]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
>   Jun 22 18:18:02 satyam-GL63-8RD apachectl[24434]: Action 'start' failed.
>   Jun 22 18:18:02 satyam-GL63-8RD apachectl[24434]: The Apache error log may have more information.
>   Jun 22 18:18:02 satyam-GL63-8RD systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zj9F.png): apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
>   Jun 22 18:18:02 satyam-GL63-8RD systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zj9F.png): apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
>   Jun 22 18:18:02 satyam-GL63-8RD systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zj9F.png): Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
>   -- Subject: Unit apache2.service has failed
>   -- Defined-By: systemd**

I checked what is already running on port:80 and the output was

```
tcp6  0  0 :::80    :::*        LISTEN      19116/httpd**
```

Also running localhost:80 on my pc gave

[image: "Ionic Blank Starter"]

but ionic is not installed on my PC. What should I do next?

Answer (score 0):

Your netstat output shows the process with PID 19116 is already bound to port 80.  Only one process can be bound to a TCP port at a given time.

You can get more information about PID 19116 by running `sudo ps -ef | grep 19116`.  If you stop that service, or kill that process, you should be able to start Apache on port 80.

Comment: I tried killing the process, as soon as I kill the process the same process restarts with some other process id.